# OpenSSL in the browser - need to get private key from .pem and then sign

Tags: javascript, openssl

I've got a php file which looks like this:

```
$key = '../certs/private/private-key-hoobu.pem';
$pass = '';

$req = $_GET['request'];
$privateKey = openssl_get_privatekey(file_get_contents($key), $pass);

$signature = null;
openssl_sign($req, $signature, $privateKey);

if($signature) {
    header("Content-type: text/plain");
    echo base64_encode($signature);
    exit(0);
}
```

I have a Windows store app I've with javascript, and for a feature I'm working on **I need to be able to recreate this code in javascript**

Now I've looked into browser-based openSSL solutions and found [node-forge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-forge) but it looks like it requires being used in like a webpack/browserify type environment, but I just need it as like a global library, don't know how to get that.

Secondly, php code above says `openssl_get_privatekey(file_get_contents($key), $pass);` but the node-forge code that I think matches, `pki.privateKeyFromPem(pem);`, doesn't even take a `$pass` variable as an argument. I'm kind of confused about that.

Comment: A private key exposed at the client-side?

Comment: In this case, as strange as it may sound, yes.